# problem with asp.net validationcontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have a textbox and I have set required validationcontrol on it on click of a button.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="name" Width="120"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvname" runat="server" ControlToValidate="name" ErrorMessage="Name is required" Display="Dynamic" />
   </td>
```

but the problem is when I am clicking on modify shared webpart and when I click on `APPLY or OK button` it is not saving as my form is empty . and I can't put
`CausesValidation="false"` on that button as this button is by default in sharepoint.

Any idea how to resolve this...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ValidationGroup` property to group all the Validators and validation fields together.

Answer (score 0):

Yes using the `ValidationGroup` tag will help to relate the controls in a single form and will tell the submit button which fields are associated. Also make sure you have a `ValidationSummary` control on the page with the same `ValidationGroup` value. Also consider adding an `InitialValue=""` onto the `TextBox` control.

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="vs1" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false" DisplayMode="List" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Form" HeaderText="There were problems with your submission:" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="name" Width="120"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvname" ValidationGroup="Form" runat="server" ControlToValidate="name" InitialValue="" ErrorMessage="Name is required" Display="Dynamic" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSubmit" Text="Submit" OnClick="lnkSubmit_Click" ValidationGroup="Form" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
```